# How do I use Micronaut views to send back params and set local storage?

Tags: java, jsp, groovy, micronaut

I am trying to use [Micronaut Views annotation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#views) to send back few params and set local storage then redirect. I used script tag inside autoredirect.html template which should set local storage and then `window.location.replace` to redirect. Please help me with following 2 concerns.

1. Request hits the post and get methods, but corresponding view is not sent back, instead after computing everything I get **404 Not Found**.

   GET request -> http://localhost:8081/someapp/api/sso
2. Is this right way to set localstorage and redirect to another relative path?

   POST request with necessary params to compute roles and JWT -> http://localhost:8081/someapp/api/sso/saml

added below additional entry in build.gradle

```
compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-views"
runtime "org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.0.11.RELEASE"
```

view location

[image]
My controller

```
@Controller('/someapp/api/sso')
@Slf4j
@CompileStatic
class SomeController {

    @View("home")
    @Get("/")
    HttpResponse index() {
        return HttpResponse.ok(CollectionUtils.mapOf("loggedIn", true, "username", "raka"))
    }

    @View("autoredirect")
    @Post('/saml')
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    HttpResponse<String> samlLogin(@Nullable @Body LinkedHashMap payload) {
        //... some operations, computing user roles & jwt 
        if (payload != null) {
            String results = handler.call(payload)
            return HttpResponse.ok(results).
            header("JWT", jwt.toString())
        } else {
            return HttpResponse.badRequest()
        }
    }
}
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" th:replace="~{layoutFile :: layout(~{::title}, ~{::section})}" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h1 th:if="${loggedIn}">username: <span th:text="${username}"></span></h1>
    <h1 th:unless="${loggedIn}">You are not logged in</h1>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

autoredirect.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cassini</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    localStorage.setItem('username', '${username}');
    localStorage.setItem('perm', '${perm}');
    localStorage.setItem('userDetails', '${userDetails}')
    window.location.replace('${redirectURL}');
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

I tried explicitly adding below lines in my application.yml, but still no luck.  Gives `13:10:56.476 [pool-2-thread-3] DEBUG io.micronaut.views.ViewsFilter - view autoredirect not found` message instead.

```
micronaut.views.enabled: true
micronaut.views.folder: views
micronaut.router.static-resources.*.enabled: true
micronaut.router.static-resources.*.paths: classpath:public
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just have an endpoint to return the users information. Then the client side can call it and do whatever needs to happen. Trying to put things in local storage then redirect in an HTML file seems like a hack to me

Comment: Also what is going wrong with Micronaut views, why isn't it rendering? Is it something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st question:

> Request hits the post and get methods, but corresponding view is not
>   sent back, instead after computing everything I get 404 Not Found.

I think you are missing the starting forward slash **/** while trying to specific view path in @View annotation.

Following basic code block renders the index.html located inside resources folder **views/home/index.html**

```
@Controller("/home")
class HomeController {

    @Get("/")
    @View("/home/index")
    public Map index() {
        return [:]
    }

}
```

For you 2nd question:

> Is this right way to set localstorage and redirect to another relative
>   path?

I am not sure completely on your requirement but if you trying to have session management and security in micronaut, you can look for

- Micronaut Session
- Micronaut Security

  ```
  @Secured([RoleConstant.SUPER_ADMIN, RoleConstant.ADMIN])
  @Controller("/home")
  class HomeController {
      @Get("/")
      @View("/home/index")
      public Map index(@Nullable Principal principal) {
          return [username: principal.name]
      }
  }
  ```

Refer documentation of Mirconaut, also make sure you upgrade to latest 1.1.1 version as few bugs are fixed in latest release for thymeleaf & cookie path used in security & session.